# Redirect An Unknown Source Domain To Subfolder Using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am interested in offering my users a "white label" service, wherein they will set up a CNAME record that points to my server.

For example, I would like **client.theirdomain.com** to actually redirect to **https://example.com/client/**, but keep the URL still as **client.theirdomain.com** (and, further, if they click a link that is actually https://example.com/client/something.html, it would appear to the user as **client.theirdomain.com/something.html**.

I attempted to do this in my .htaccess with the following;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^client\.(.*)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /client [NC,L]
```

For posterity, I also have a valid subdomain created (client.example.com) that directs to the root of my website, as well as a CNAME record created on a client's server (which points client.theirdomain.com to client.example.com).

When I attempt to use the above settings, however, I receive an error that there were too many redirects.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `http://client.theirdomain.com` work fine at present?

Comment: Hi @anubhava - Yes, if I do not add anything to my .htaccess file, then visiting http://client.theirdomain.com directs properly to my /var/www/html/ folder, as I would expect it to.

Comment: so what URL is not working as you expect?

Comment: @anubhava - Sorry, updated with the exact error.  I receive that there were too many redirects.

Comment: That is strange because your htacceas doesn't have any redirect rule. Can you post your full htacceas by editing your question